# Android Updade RecyclerView data

Tags: android

i'm trying to reload data for `recyclerView` for below code. but it doesnt work correctly for example with:

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
long count = Utils.getLocalContactsList(getContentResolver(), realm);
if (count > 0) {
    results = realm.where(ContactLists.class).findAll();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcontactLists);
    adapter = new ContactsAdapter(results, getApplication());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}else{
    Utils.toast(Utils.getString(R.string.there_is_no_contacts), getBaseContext());
}
```

i can fill recyclerView and that work fine, but after fetch some data from webservice and update database i must be reload recyclerView, but this part of my code dont work fine:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(fetch_server_url, new JSONArray(wordList),
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject   = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String     mobileNumber = jsonObject.getString("mobileNumber");
                        ContactLists exists_row = realm.where(ContactLists.class).equalTo("mobile_number", mobileNumber).findFirst();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        if (exists_row != null) {
                            exists_row.setIsRegistered("1");
                        } else {
                            exists_row.setIsRegistered("0");
                        }
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                results = realm.where(ContactLists.class).findAll();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //Log.e
    }
});
```

problem is this lines:

```
results = realm.where(ContactLists.class).findAll();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My recyclerView Adapter:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomContactsViewHolder> {

    List<ContactLists> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<ContactLists> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View                     v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
        CustomContactsViewHolder holder = new CustomContactsViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomContactsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(list.get(position).getContact_name());
        holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getMobile_number());
        if (list.get(position).getIsRegistered().equals("1"))
            holder.img_logo.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.epay_logo));
        else
            holder.img_logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to update the Adapter with the new data.

```
results = realm.where(ContactLists.class).findAll();
adapter.setData(results);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Where setData does:

```
public void setData(List<ContactLists> list) {
        this.list = list;
}
```